# UITextView inputAccessoryView not behaving properly on safe area phones?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, uitextview

I am trying use UIKit's UITextView in an swiftUI project using UIViewRepresentable. Everything works great but I am facing some issue with inputAccessoryView on phones with safe area.
My inputAccessoryView is a swiftUI view wrapped in UIHostingController which lets me use swiftUI views as UIView.
I have attached my code and some images, To simplify my issue I am using simple swiftUI colorView as inputAccessoryView. As you can see the swiftUI view moves out of the frame of inputAccessoryView when it comes near bottom safe area. When you swipe down to close the keyboard it disappears weirdly. I have tried everything but could not find the solution. Can you please help me?

Thank You!

UIViewRepresentable, UITextView

```
struct UITextViewWrapper: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let textView = UITextView()
        textView.text = text
        textView.inputAccessoryView = makeKeyboardBar()
        textView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        textView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
        
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        //
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        let parent: UITextViewWrapper
        
        init(_ parent: UITextViewWrapper) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            parent.text = textView.text
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    func makeKeyboardBar() -> UIView {
        let swiftUIView = ColorView()
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)
        
        let uiView = hostingController.view!
        uiView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: hostingController.sizeThatFits(in: uiView.frame.size))
        
        uiView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        uiView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        
        return uiView
    }
}
```

SwiftUI View to use as inputAccessoryView

```
struct ColorView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow
        .frame(height: 55)
    }
}
```

ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text = "Hello World"
    
    var body: some View {
        UITextViewWrapper(text: $text)
    }
}
```

image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SwiftUI has own safe area tracking so you have to manage safe area behaviour explicitly inside SwiftUI view, like

```
var body: some View {
    Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)  // << here !!
    .frame(height: 55)
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. This doesn't work, the inputAccessoryView still going out of the frame. This time it expands in height.